# Multiple variables acting as a single independent variable

Tags: functions

If you have a function f(x+y)=(x-y)(x+y), is it still a function of (x+y)?  I would say no, because both x and y, constituent variables of the independent variable, appear in the equation, which is supposed to strictly be a function of (x+y)?

Answer (score 2):

Saying that an expression "is a function of $x+y$" means that the value of the expression depends *only* on the value of $x+y$. That is not true here.

For example, consider $x = 1, y = 0$. Then $x+y = 1$ and $(x-y)(x+y) = 1$.

Next, consider $x = 2, y = -1$. Then again $x+y = 1$, but $(x-y)(x+y) = 3$.

Since the value of $(x-y)(x+y)$ does not depend only on the value of $x+y$. $(x-y)(x+y)$ is not a function of $x+y$.

Also, it doesn't make sense to say $f(x+y) = (x-y)(x+y)$ here, since the expression $(x-y)(x+y)$ is not written in terms of $x+y$. Instead, you should say $f(x,y) = (x-y)(x+y)$.